# D receiveFrom not recieving full packet

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, d

I'm currently using D to write a small UDP server for a game. The problem is that some packets received do not match the length of the actual packets (viewed via wireshark).

For example, the client sends a 110 byte packet over the network, which shows up under wireshark. But the D code only receives 7 bytes! There are NO other 7 byte packets being sent over the network from the client.

The 7 bytes from D match the first 7 bytes from the 110 byte packet. I believe it is a problem with the socket library, as I can't think of anything else that could cause this problem.

The problem always occurs at the same point and exact same packet. If ignored, the problem continues for certain packets.

Please note that there are multiple files in this project, so I included snips of the code below:

```d
this(in Logger logger, string bindInterface = "0.0.0.0", ushort bindPort = 19132) {
    this.logger = logger;
    socket = new UdpSocket(AddressFamily.INET);
    bindAddress = new InternetAddress(bindInterface, bindPort);
}

void bind(uint sendBufferSize = 1024 * 1024, uint recvBufferSize = 1024 * 1024) {
    socket.bind(bindAddress);

    socket.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET, SocketOption.BROADCAST, true);
    socket.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET, SocketOption.SNDBUF, sendBufferSize);
    socket.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET, SocketOption.RCVBUF, recvBufferSize);
    socket.blocking = false;
}

bool recv(ref Address address, ref byte[] buffer) {
    auto length = socket.receiveFrom(buffer, SocketFlags.NONE, address);
    if(length > 0) {
        buffer.length = length;
        debug logger.logDebug(to!string(length) ~ " Packet IN: " ~ to!string(cast(ubyte[]) buffer));
        return true;
    }
    buffer = null;
    return false;
}
```

...

```d
Address a;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    while(max-- > 0 && socket.recv(a, data)) {
        handlePacket(a, data);
    }
```

Full source can be found [here.](https://github.com/jython234/DRakLib)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The client is

Comment: Can you see the exact content of the entire message being sent?  Not what you believe it is but what content is actually being sent?

Comment: It's unlikely. UDP deliver the complete message or nothing. It's the only guarantee that UDP makes. So if what you say is true, something is very broken in your network infrastructure, your OS or in the code compiler.

Comment: @zipzit If you mean through wireshark, yes, the whole content shows up. The data in question are binary handshake packets part of the RakNet protocol.

Comment: @jgauffin I never had this problem before with other languages on this computer, which is why I believe it is a D problem.

Comment: @jython234 My bad.  I'm not into D, but what I want to know is if you do the equivalent of `log.console(value_about_to_be_sent);` in the SENDER program what do you see there?  Does that match exactly what you think you are sending?  My guess is you're sending unknow (control) characters erroneously?  (but that's just a wild guess?)

Comment: @zipzit I wish that were possible, but the client game is minecraft: PE, so its not possible. That is what makes it hard to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with this line:

```d
bool recv(ref Address address, ref byte[] buffer)
```

With `ref` you does not make slice but you really modify original buffer so if previous packet is 7bytes long than you can not receive more than 7 bytes anymore

So you can change your code to remove ref and return length instead of plain bool

```d
size_t recv(ref Address address, byte[] buffer);
```

and then:

```d
Address a;
byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
size_t len;
while(max-- > 0 && (len = socket.recv(a, data))) {
    handlePacket(a, data[0 .. len]);
}
```

But this will probably do not work with your `handlePacket` function because of another `ref` so another variant is to do not change your `recv` but only part of code arount `handlePacket`

```d
Address a;
byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
size_t arr = data[];
while(max-- > 0 && socket.recv(a, arr)) {
    handlePacket(a, arr);
    arr = data[];
}
```

Comment: He can't simply remove the ref because he needs the updated `.length` for `handlePacket`. But one problem is indeed that after the first recv call the `data` buffer passed to `receiveFrom` is too small. Possible solutions: Remove the `ref` but return the updated slice from `recv` and use that for `handlePacket`. Or keep `recv` unmodified and reset `data` to the complete buffer size after `handlePacket`.

Comment: @jpf yes, I modified my answer to make it more accurate

Comment: Could you go more in depth for why `ref byte[] buffer` only accepts 7 bytes? That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @MaikKlein when you look at https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/v2.071.0/std/socket.d#L3041 you will see that buf.length is used. And in code above he change buf.length to length of last packet. So when he receive packet with size of 7 bytes, than in next call there will be only 7 bytes read from socket.